# Call public function in User Control WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF

I have many master forms.which is having some buttons in all forms.so i wrote that button handing in usercontrols and using this same in all other master forms
now i want to handle each button.for that i wrote code on each form and trying to access it to user control class. but i couldn't. How can i do it ?

I have 3 forms

1)Aform

2)BForm

3)CForm

each form having 2 button.Say Save and Delete

Each form have to differently handle these buttons. So i wrote code on each form as function or Sub

Now I want to call that function to user control..'
I tried  like this

in AForm.Vb :

```
Public Sub SaveA()
{}
```

In UserControl :

```
Dim ParentControl as Window=Window.GetWindow(me)

ParentControl.SaveA () // But i couldn't
```

What  can i do for this ?

Comment: You want to invoke parent form's function inside the user control?

Comment: When working with WPF you may want to lookup MVVM and the command pattern. If you continue WPF like you did in VB (or C# WinForms) you will miss out on some very cool features.

Comment: Yes i want to  invoke parent form's function inside the user control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to type-cast the `Window` object to your specific `Window` implementation. For example given you defined the function in `MainWindow` class :

```
Dim ParentControl as MainWindow = CType(Window.GetWindow(me), MainWindow)
ParentControl.SaveA()
```